Cassandra "Unable to find java executable" in Linux Ubuntu
I have installed openjdk-8, so i can successfully check:
seva@seva-HLYL-WXX9:~$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_432"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_432-8u432-ga~us1-0ubuntu2~24.04-ga)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.432-bga, mixed mode)

seva@seva-HLYL-WXX9:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

seva@seva-HLYL-WXX9:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/opt/idea-IU-243.22562.218/bin:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_431/bin:/opt/idea-IU-243.22562.218/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin

I also have installed cassandra 4.0 how its was described in documentation. But when i run cassandra or nodetool then i receive message:
seva@seva-HLYL-WXX9:~$ sudo cassandra
Unable to find java executable. Check JAVA_HOME and PATH environment variables.


Why are you running cassandra with sudo?

@Sören i read on the internet, that cassandra needs sudo. Otherwise, it has no permissions to some files. Should I not use sudo?

When you use sudo most environment variables are not passed from your environment to the environment of your child process.  Yoiu can read about it in the manual entries for sudo and sudoers.  If you are going to change the sudoers file, use visudo to do it safely.

Not sure if your sudo reason is a good one but you could try sudo -E. Also not sure why such an old jdk is needed

Latest Cassandra supports at least Java 17
